# C++ multiple nested If-else statements work but combined doesn't

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm a newbie to c++. I attempted a questions related to bitsets(https://www.codechef.com/problems/CHEFQUE),
when I use the following nested statements the code passes all the tests

```
    for(int i=1;i<Q+1;i++){
        temp = S/2;
        if(S&1){ //odd
            if(!sets[temp]){
                sets[temp] = true;
                sum+=temp;
            }
        }
        else{    //even
            if(sets[temp]){
                sets[temp] = false;
                sum-=temp;
            }
        }
        S = (A*S + B);
```

But when I combine the multiple if-else statements, it fails on some tests

```
    for(int i=1;i<Q+1;i++){
        temp = S/2;
        if(S&1 && !sets[temp]){ //odd and empty
            sets[temp] = true;
            sum+=temp;
        }
        else if(!S&1 && sets[temp]){    //even ond occupied
            sets[temp] = false;
            sum-=temp;
        }
        S = (A*S + B);
    }
```

I really have no clue why this would happen, I'm sure it must be really stupid. I would really be thankful if someone helped.

Comment: `!` has (much) higher precedence than `&`.

Comment: The lesson here, and it is an important one, is to be liberal with parenthesis.  Anytime I have any doubt of OOO, I use parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from [this table](https://it.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) the operator `!` has a higher precedence that `&` (Bitwise and, not address of), so your code should looks like this:

```
    for(int i=1;i<Q+1;i++){
    temp = S/2;
    if(S&1 && !sets[temp]){ //odd and empty
        sets[temp] = true;
        sum+=temp;
    }
    else if(!(S&1) && sets[temp]){    //even ond occupied
        sets[temp] = false;
        sum-=temp;
    }
    S = (A*S + B);
}
```